# Why cannot move DOM nodes in Chrome anymore?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

I am not able to move the DOM nodes in the Google Chrome, in the Inspect Element tab, when I select them and try to grab/drag them nothing happens anymore. 
I have reset the settings on both the browser and the dev tool, but there is no change.

In case you wonder what I am referring to, please click on this link: [**Move DOM node**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom#move_dom_node).

**Chrome version**: *73.0.3664.3 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)*

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Can you please check? Is it 73.0.3664.3?

Comment: I have the same problem for Chrome Canary (Version 75.0.3746.0) but it works fine in the standard Chrome app (Version 73.0.3683.86). Curious. Just started to be an issue in the last couple of weeks (with Canary).

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to move DOM Nodes in the elements tab of the inspector by clicking and holding - I'm on Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit) FWIW.